# How can I increase the maximum file name size of attachments in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

On Prestashop 1.7, how can I increase the maximum file name size of attachments?
While naming attachment files in the Back Office, I encounter the following error message.

[image]

How can I go around this problem in Prestashop 1.7? I looked up online and found some solutions for Prestashop 1.5 or 1.6, but not for 1.7.

Here are some links that I followed:

- https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/63332-bug-the-field-mime-is-too-long-32-chars-max/?tab=comments#comment-1189602
- https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/81129-solvedhow-to-change-the-length-of-the-file-name-of-the-attachement/?tab=comments#comment-1197114

Following the above links, I have tried:

- In the DB, changed the 'name' column's type in the 'ps_attachment_lang' table to 'varchar(128)'.
- In Attachment.php (/classes/Attachment.php), made sure the size is 128.

```php
'name' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128],
```

- In AdminProductsController.php (/controllers/admin/AdminProductsController.php), changed a part of function ajaxProcessAddAttachment(), from

```php
if (!Validate::isGenericName($name)) {
  $_FILES['attachment_file']['error'][] = $this->trans('Invalid name for %s language', [$language['name']], 'Admin.Notifications.Error');
} elseif (Tools::strlen($name) > 32) {
  $_FILES['attachment_file']['error'][] = $this->trans('The name for %1s language is too long (%2d chars max).', [$language['name'], 32], 'Admin.Notifications.Error');
}
```

to

```php
if (!Validate::isGenericName($name)) {
  $_FILES['attachment_file']['error'][] = $this->trans('Invalid name for %s language', [$language['name']], 'Admin.Notifications.Error');
} elseif (Tools::strlen($name) > 64) {
  $_FILES['attachment_file']['error'][] = $this->trans('The name for %1s language is too long (%2d chars max).', [$language['name'], 64], 'Admin.Notifications.Error');
}
```

But unfortunately, none of them worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is my own question but I found one solution.

In the AttachmentConstraint.php (in /src/Core/Domain/Attachment/Configuration/AttachmentConstraint.php), find the line

```php
const MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 32;
```

and change it to whatever number that is lower than your database table can hold:

```php
//const MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 32; 
const MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 128; // this number needs to be lower than `name` column in `ps_attachment_lang` table
```

This should do the trick, but this solution requires changes in the core file. If there's anyone who knows a way we can achieve this without modifying the core files, please share that.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered the same problem.

What I've done is all through a module, but with the override of Attachment.php.

The Presta version where I've used the module is 8.0.3, but I think it will work with a 1.7.X too

- I've created [a decoration](https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/modules/concepts/controllers/admin-controllers/override-decorate-controller/) of AttachmentType:

yourmodule/config/services.yml

```yaml
services:
  attachment_type_decorator:
    class: YourNamespace\AttachmentTypeDecorator
    decorates: prestashop.bundle.form.admin.sell.attachment.attachment
    arguments:
      - "@attachment_type_decorator.inner"
      - "@translator"
```

yourmodule/src/Form/AttachmentTypeDecorator.php

```php
<?php
/* ...
namespace and uses
... */
class AttachmentTypeDecorator extends AttachmentType
{
    public const MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 64;

    /**
     * @var AttachmentType
     */
    private $decoratedController;

    public function __construct(AttachmentType $decoratedController, $translator)
    {
        $this->decoratedController = $decoratedController;
        $this->translator = $translator;

    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->decoratedController->buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder->remove('name');
        $builder
            ->add('name', TranslatableType::class, [
                'type' => TextType::class,
                'required' => true,
                'label' => $this->translator->trans('File name', [], 'Admin.Global'),
                'options' => [
                    'constraints' => [
                        new TypedRegex(
                            [
                                'type' => 'generic_name',
                            ]
                        ),
                        new Length(
                            [
                                'max' => self::MAX_NAME_LENGTH,
                                'maxMessage' => $this->translator->trans(
                                    'This field cannot be longer than %limit% characters',
                                    ['%limit%' => self::MAX_NAME_LENGTH],
                                    'Admin.Notifications.Error'
                                ),
                            ]
                        ),
                    ],
                ],
                'constraints' => [
                    new DefaultLanguage(),
                ],
            ]);
    }
}
```

- Modified the attachment_lang table with sql in a "install.php" file using AttachmentTypeDecorator MAX_NAME_LENGTH const:

```php
$sql_override = 'SELECT character_maximum_length
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = "' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'attachment_lang" AND column_name = "name"';

$length = Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql_override);

if($length && intval($length) < AttachmentTypeDecorator::MAX_NAME_LENGTH) {
    $sql_change = 'ALTER TABLE `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'attachment_lang`
    MODIFY `name`
    varchar('.AttachmentTypeDecorator::MAX_NAME_LENGTH.');';
    Db::getInstance()->execute($sql_change);
}
```

Consider to put an alter table that restore 32 as varchar size of name's column in the uninstall process.

- Created an override of Attachment.php:

yourmodule/override/classes/Attachment.php

```php
<?php
use YourNamespace\AttachmentTypeDecorator;
class Attachment extends AttachmentCore
{
    public function __construct($id = null, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, $translator = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($id, $id_lang, $id_shop, $translator);
        self::$definition['fields']['name']['size'] = AttachmentTypeDecorator::MAX_NAME_LENGTH;
    }
}
```

And that's all.